# SQL Compare 2 Tables for Differences Takes Long Time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with ~900k records each and need to check whether one of the tables is missing some records. I have attempted numerous suggestions found online, including this one:

```
SELECT tableB.ColumnOfInterest, tableB.City, tableB.Province 
FROM tableB 
WHERE tableB.ColumnOfInterest NOT IN (SELECT TableA.ColumnOfInterest 
                                      FROM TableA)
```

however, the query seems to hang. 5 minutes later, and it is still querying.

Is there a way to accomplish this comparison / difference detection faster?

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you trying to detect missing rows or missing columns?

Comment: Try doing a LEFT JOIN by ColumnName WHERE TableA.someOtherColumn IS NULL

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm trying to detect missing rows using the values of one column as the comparison criteria.

Comment: Oh, I see.  `ColumnName` is a placeholder for a real column name.  Some RDBMS's actually have system tables with a column called "ColumnName".

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you, I've edited my question to address this.

Comment: have look here: https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/ It may reveal the fact `NOT IN` should be a good solution for your problem in MySQL.

Comment: Do you have an index on `TableA.ColumnOfInterest` and `tableB.ColumnOfInterest`?

Comment: @RadimBača I do not, would that cut the time down a good amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a left join instead of a 'not in' subquery to increase performance

```
 SELECT a.ColumnOfInterest , a.City, a.Province 
    FROM tableB a
    left join TableA b on a.ColumnOfInterest =b.ColumnOfInterest 
    where b.ColumnOfInterest is null
```

Comment: I have seen this make a query that ran for several hours turn into a query that ran in a few minutes.

Comment: I tried this, though I get the following error: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'tableB.ColumnName' in 'field list'

Comment: Think OP changed it to 'columnofinterest'

Comment: @DanielMarcus I changed it to ColumnOfInterest because it's been pointed out to me that ColumnName had special meaning, but I've tried it with the actual column name and still get the same error.

Comment: I see ok see adjusted code - I created aliases on the join and i had to reflect those in the select sorry

Comment: @DanielMarcus Thank you, I get go error and the query begins running, however it is still taking a long time / has not finished after 5 minutes. How long would this select take for 2 columns of ~900k records each?

Comment: Impossible to say - it depends on lots of things like what else is running in the environment at the time, are there any locks taking place, the speed of your system etc - i can tell you that using a left join should be faster than a 'not in' subquery just about all of the time - the actual time it will take though is anybody's guess

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists` instead

```
SELECT ColumnName, City, Province 
FROM tableB b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA WHERE ColumnName = b.ColumnName);
```

However, this want index on `tableB(ColumnName)` /  `TableA(ColumnName)`

Comment: It's still a subquery.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it may still be better than the original query if the size of the original subquery's results is bottlenecking things. I am not generally a fan of correlated subqueries, but this is one place they _can sometimes_ help. That said, I'd still go with a join solution first.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) there is not a significant difference between a solution using not in and left join+not null. The major issue in your case may be a lack of the following indexes:

```
Create index ix_tb_col on tableB(ColumnOfInterest)

Create index ix_ta_col on tableA(ColumnOfInterest)
```